# Getting Exception: Invalid PBX project (parsing line 0) when running iOS build on Unity3D

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to nail this one down for weeks. I haven't been able to come up with a solution to correct this. I'm using the latest GoogleMobileAds.

> Exception: Invalid PBX project (parsing line 0)
>   UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBX.Parser.ParseTree () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/XCode/PBX/Parser.cs:114)
>   UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBXProjectData.ParseContent (System.String
>   content) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/XCode/PBXProjectData.cs:451)
>   UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBXProjectData.ReadFromStream
>   (System.IO.TextReader sr) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/XCode/PBXProjectData.cs:458)
>   UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.ReadFromStream (System.IO.TextReader
>   sr) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/XCode/PBXProject.cs:868)
>   UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.ReadFromString (System.String src)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/XCode/PBXProject.cs:863)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Postprocessor.runPodUpdate (System.String path) (at
>   Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/PostProcessor.cs:56)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Postprocessor.OnPostprocessBuild (BuildTarget target,
>   System.String pathToBuiltProject) (at
>   Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/PostProcessor.cs:27)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I just updated to Xcode 8 and I keep getting this error also.

Comment: @JulioGarcia I just ignore it and build the project in XCode